# how can I append the facebook status textbox to my website

Tags: php, css, facebook, status

Can Any one please help me. I want this textbox to be visible on my website and the users can update their status directly from the website. Thankyou in advance

[image: facebook status text box]

Answer (score 1):

The facebook API don't provide such functionality.

You may make the similar looking text box of our own, and use **feed** to update their status.

[Sample Code](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/facebook-graph-api-to-post-status.html).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to Create a new App for your Site https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Then after creating the App,by using the API Key and App Secret with the Help of OAuth Protocol you need to Integrate as shown in their following

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Then Include these two files then you give action to the Post Button.

Comment: I have already created an app and I am able to publish through the facebook api FEED method. but the problem is that I need to show the text area with post button on my website.. is it possible??

Comment: @NabeelArshad you need to create the UI for this by yourself. No direct method for this.